# Ended up with two YouTube accounts, how to merge?

Tags: youtube

I had a Google account that I used to use for subscriptions and watching stuff over the past few months. Then I tried to comment on a video, it popped up a dialog asking me to create a YouTube Channel (which I believe also created a Google plus page). On creating the channel I seem to have two YouTube profiles now:

- The original one with my view history and subscriptions
- The new one without any subscriptions or view history, but has comment capabilities.

I can currently switch between both profiles by clicking the button on the top right.

How can I either enable commenting on my original profile, or migrate view history and subscriptions to the new profile?

Comment: You can’t merge two YouTube accounts.